# Run more loops at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, loops, tkinter

First of all, I have to say that I'm a beginner in Python. These are my first steps in creating a class. And now my question.[On that picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9CRd.png), I presented what my code should work.

1. Start the program (Run)
2. Check what instruments should be power on. There are three
   possibilities and you can power one, two or all three Units at the
   same time. (Power #A/B/C)
3. Furthermore, with each power unit additional you can turn on
   Temperatur sensor (Temp. #A,B,C)
4. Depending on which units are involved to run a Loop #A, #B, #C or
   for example two units #B,#C or perhaps all three.This is actually my Problem and question. How can be able to simultaneously also at
   the same time, run two or maybe even three loops ?

**I hope you can give me some advice and help in solving my problem.**

Below I will put my code so you can refer and pay Attention what I could change or improve in my code.

```
import Tkinter
import visa, time, datetime
from ttk import *
from tkFileDialog import *
import tkMessageBox, os
import numpy as np

rm = visa.ResourceManager()
inst = rm.list_resources()

class Interface:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        parent.title("Cycling")
        local_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        self.dataname = "/does/not/exist"

    # Frame
        self.frame_instruments = Tkinter.Frame(parent, bg='', colormap='new')
        self.frame_settings = Tkinter.Frame(parent, bg='', colormap='new')
        self.frame_image = Tkinter.Frame(parent, bg='', colormap='new')

    # Labelframe
        self.lframe_instrumet_a = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self.frame_instruments, text="Choose an Instruments - #A", padx=8, pady=9)
        self.lframe_settings_a = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self.frame_instruments, text="Settings - #A", padx=7, pady=11)

        self.lframe_instrumet_b = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self.frame_instruments, text="Choose an Instruments - #B", padx=8, pady=9)
        self.lframe_settings_b = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self.frame_instruments, text="Settings - #B", padx=7, pady=11)

        self.lframe_instrumet_c = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self.frame_instruments, text="Choose an Instruments - #C", padx=8, pady=9)
        self.lframe_settings_c = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self.frame_instruments, text="Settings - #C", padx=7, pady=11)

    # Combobox
        #A
        self.choices_power_supply_a_var = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.choices_power_supply_a_var.set(inst[0])
        self.combo_power_supply_a = Combobox(self.lframe_instrumet_a, values=inst, textvariable=self.choices_power_supply_a_var)

        self.choices_multimeter_a_var = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.choices_multimeter_a_var.set(inst[0])
        self.combo_multimeter_a = Combobox(self.lframe_instrumet_a, values=inst, textvariable=self.choices_multimeter_a_var)

        #B
        self.choices_power_supply_b_var = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.choices_power_supply_b_var.set(inst[0])
        self.combo_power_supply_b = Combobox(self.lframe_instrumet_b, values=inst, textvariable=self.choices_power_supply_b_var)

        self.choices_multimeter_b_var = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.choices_multimeter_b_var.set(inst[0])
        self.combo_multimeter_b = Combobox(self.lframe_instrumet_b, values=inst, textvariable=self.choices_multimeter_b_var)

        #C
        self.choices_power_supply_c_var = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.choices_power_supply_c_var.set(inst[0])
        self.combo_power_supply_c = Combobox(self.lframe_instrumet_c, values=inst, textvariable=self.choices_power_supply_c_var)

        self.choices_multimeter_c_var = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.choices_multimeter_c_var.set(inst[0])
        self.combo_multimeter_c = Combobox(self.lframe_instrumet_c, values=inst, textvariable=self.choices_multimeter_c_var)

    # Menu
        menu = Tkinter.Menu(parent, tearoff=0)
        parent.config(menu=menu)
        filemenu = Tkinter.Menu(parent, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=filemenu)
        filemenu.add_command(label='Create New File...', command=lambda: self.save_file())
        helpmenu = Tkinter.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label='?', menu=helpmenu)
        helpmenu.add_command(label='About', command=lambda: self.about())

    # Label
        #A
        self.label_power_supply_a = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_instrumet_a, text="Power Supply 2200: ")
        self.label_multimeter_a = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_instrumet_a, text="Multimeter 2700: ")
        self.label_voltage_range_a = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_a, text='Voltage Range [V]')
        self.label_over_voltage_a = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_a, text='Over Voltage Protection [V]')
        self.label_voltage_set_a = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_a, text='Set Voltage [V]')
        self.label_heat_set_a = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_a, text='Heat.Set [A]')
        self.label_meas_set_a = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_a, text='Meas. Set [A]')
        self.label_set_time_a = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_a, text='Time Limit [s]')
        self.label_set_delay_a = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_a, text='Measurement Delay [s]')
        self.label_set_repeat_a = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_a, text='Repeat')

        #B
        self.label_power_supply_b = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_instrumet_b, text="Power Supply 2200: ")
        self.label_multimeter_b = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_instrumet_b, text="Multimeter 2700: ")
        self.label_voltage_range_b = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_b, text='Voltage Range [V]')
        self.label_over_voltage_b = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_b, text='Over Voltage Protection [V]')
        self.label_voltage_set_b = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_b, text='Set Voltage [V]')
        self.label_heat_set_b = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_b, text='Heat.Set [A]')
        self.label_meas_set_b = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_b, text='Meas. Set [A]')
        self.label_set_time_b = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_b, text='Time Limit [s]')
        self.label_set_delay_b = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_b, text='Measurement Delay [s]')
        self.label_set_repeat_b = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_b, text='Repeat')

        #C
        self.label_power_supply_c = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_instrumet_c, text="Power Supply 2200: ")
        self.label_multimeter_c = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_instrumet_c, text="Multimeter 2700: ")
        self.label_voltage_range_c = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_c, text='Voltage Range [V]')
        self.label_over_voltage_c = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_c, text='Over Voltage Protection [V]')
        self.label_voltage_set_c = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_c, text='Set Voltage [V]')
        self.label_heat_set_c = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_c, text='Heat.Set [A]')
        self.label_meas_set_c = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_c, text='Meas. Set [A]')
        self.label_set_time_c = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_c, text='Time Limit [s]')
        self.label_set_delay_c = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_c, text='Measurement Delay [s]')
        self.label_set_repeat_c = Tkinter.Label(self.lframe_settings_c, text='Repeat')

    # Checkbutton
        #A
        self.temp_sensor_a_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.check_temp_sensor_a = Checkbutton(self.lframe_instrumet_a, text="Temperatursensor - #A", variable=self.temp_sensor_a_var,
                                               onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        self.instrument_var_a = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.check_instrument_a = Checkbutton(self.lframe_settings_a, text="Instrument - #A", variable=self.instrument_var_a,
                                               onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        #B
        self.temp_sensor_b_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.check_temp_sensor_b = Checkbutton(self.lframe_instrumet_b, text="Temperatursensor - #B", variable=self.temp_sensor_b_var,
                                               onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        self.instrument_var_b = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.check_instrument_b = Checkbutton(self.lframe_settings_b, text="Instrument - #B", variable=self.instrument_var_b,
                                               onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        #C
        self.temp_sensor_c_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.check_temp_sensor_c = Checkbutton(self.lframe_instrumet_c, text="Temperatursensor - #C", variable=self.temp_sensor_c_var,
                                               onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        self.instrument_var_c = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.check_instrument_c = Checkbutton(self.lframe_settings_c, text="Instrument - #C", variable=self.instrument_var_c,
                                               onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    # Entry/Spinbox
        #A
        self.voltage_range_a_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.spin_voltage_range_a = Tkinter.Spinbox(self.lframe_settings_a, textvariable=self.voltage_range_a_var, width=5,
                                                    from_=0, to=30, justify='right')
        self.over_voltage_a_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.spin_over_voltage_a = Tkinter.Spinbox(self.lframe_settings_a, textvariable=self.over_voltage_a_var, width=5,
                                                   from_=0, to=30, justify='right')
        self.heat_set_a_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_heat_set_a = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_a, textvariable=self.heat_set_a_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.meas_set_a_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_meas_set_a = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_a, textvariable=self.meas_set_a_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.voltage_set_a_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_voltage_set_a = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_a, textvariable=self.voltage_set_a_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.time_set_a_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_time_set_a = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_a, textvariable=self.time_set_a_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.delay_set_a_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_delay_set_a = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_a, textvariable=self.delay_set_a_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.repeat_set_a_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_repeat_set_a = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_a, textvariable=self.repeat_set_a_var, width=7, justify='right')

        #B
        self.voltage_range_b_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.spin_voltage_range_b = Tkinter.Spinbox(self.lframe_settings_b, textvariable=self.voltage_range_b_var, width=5,
                                                    from_=0, to=30, justify='right')
        self.over_voltage_b_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.spin_over_voltage_b = Tkinter.Spinbox(self.lframe_settings_b, textvariable=self.over_voltage_b_var, width=5,
                                                   from_=0, to=30, justify='right')
        self.heat_set_b_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_heat_set_b = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_b, textvariable=self.heat_set_b_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.meas_set_b_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_meas_set_b = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_b, textvariable=self.meas_set_b_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.voltage_set_b_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_voltage_set_b = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_b, textvariable=self.voltage_set_b_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.time_set_b_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_time_set_b = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_b, textvariable=self.time_set_b_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.delay_set_b_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_delay_set_b = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_b, textvariable=self.delay_set_b_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.repeat_set_b_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_repeat_set_b = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_b, textvariable=self.repeat_set_b_var, width=7, justify='right')

        #C
        self.voltage_range_c_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.spin_voltage_range_c = Tkinter.Spinbox(self.lframe_settings_c, textvariable=self.voltage_range_c_var, width=5,
                                                    from_=0, to=30, justify='right')
        self.over_voltage_c_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.spin_over_voltage_c = Tkinter.Spinbox(self.lframe_settings_c, textvariable=self.over_voltage_c_var, width=5,
                                                   from_=0, to=30, justify='right')
        self.heat_set_c_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_heat_set_c = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_c, textvariable=self.heat_set_c_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.meas_set_c_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_meas_set_c = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_c, textvariable=self.meas_set_c_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.voltage_set_c_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_voltage_set_c = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_c, textvariable=self.voltage_set_c_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.time_set_c_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_time_set_c = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_c, textvariable=self.time_set_c_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.delay_set_c_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_delay_set_c = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_c, textvariable=self.delay_set_c_var, width=7, justify='right')

        self.repeat_set_c_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.entry_repeat_set_c = Tkinter.Entry(self.lframe_settings_c, textvariable=self.repeat_set_c_var, width=7, justify='right')

    # Button
        self.button_run = Tkinter.Button(self.frame_settings, text="Run", command=lambda: self.on_run(), width=25)
        self.button_stop = Tkinter.Button(self.frame_settings, text="Stop", command=lambda: self.on_stop(), width=25)
        self.button_quit = Tkinter.Button(self.frame_settings, text="Quit", command=lambda: self.on_quit(), width=25)

    # Grid
        parent.resizable(False, False)
        parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)

        # Instrument #A
        self.frame_instruments.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.lframe_instrumet_a.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label_power_supply_a.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='W')
        self.label_multimeter_a.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='W')
        self.combo_power_supply_a.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.combo_multimeter_a.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.check_temp_sensor_a.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.lframe_settings_a.grid(row=0, column=2)
        self.label_voltage_range_a.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='W')
        self.spin_voltage_range_a.grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.label_over_voltage_a.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='W')
        self.label_heat_set_a.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='W')
        self.spin_over_voltage_a.grid(row=1, column=3)
        self.entry_heat_set_a.grid(row=2, column=3)
        self.label_voltage_set_a.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='W')
        self.label_meas_set_a.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky='W')
        self.label_set_time_a.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky='W')
        self.entry_voltage_set_a.grid(row=0, column=5)
        self.entry_meas_set_a.grid(row=1, column=5)
        self.entry_time_set_a.grid(row=2, column=5)
        self.label_set_delay_a.grid(row=0, column=6, sticky='W')
        self.label_set_repeat_a.grid(row=1, column=6, sticky='W')
        self.entry_delay_set_a.grid(row=0, column=7)
        self.entry_repeat_set_a.grid(row=1, column=7)
        self.check_instrument_a.grid(row=2, column=6, sticky='W')

        # Instrument #B
        self.lframe_instrumet_b.grid(row=3)
        self.label_power_supply_b.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.label_multimeter_b.grid(row=4, column=0)
        self.combo_power_supply_b.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.combo_multimeter_b.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.check_temp_sensor_b.grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.lframe_settings_b.grid(row=3, column=2)
        self.label_voltage_range_b.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='W')
        self.spin_voltage_range_b.grid(row=3, column=3)
        self.label_over_voltage_b.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='W')
        self.label_heat_set_b.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky='W')
        self.spin_over_voltage_b.grid(row=4, column=3)
        self.entry_heat_set_b.grid(row=5, column=3)
        self.label_voltage_set_b.grid(row=3, column=4, sticky='W')
        self.label_meas_set_b.grid(row=4, column=4, sticky='W')
        self.label_set_time_b.grid(row=5, column=4, sticky='W')
        self.entry_voltage_set_b.grid(row=3, column=5)
        self.entry_meas_set_b.grid(row=4, column=5)
        self.entry_time_set_b.grid(row=5, column=5)
        self.label_set_delay_b.grid(row=3, column=6, sticky='W')
        self.label_set_repeat_b.grid(row=4, column=6, sticky='W')
        self.entry_delay_set_b.grid(row=3, column=7)
        self.entry_repeat_set_b.grid(row=4, column=7)
        self.check_instrument_b.grid(row=5, column=6, sticky='W')

         # Instrument #C
        self.lframe_instrumet_c.grid(row=6)
        self.label_power_supply_c.grid(row=6, column=0)
        self.label_multimeter_c.grid(row=7, column=0)
        self.combo_power_supply_c.grid(row=6, column=1)
        self.combo_multimeter_c.grid(row=7, column=1)
        self.check_temp_sensor_c.grid(row=8, column=1)

        self.lframe_settings_c.grid(row=6, column=2)
        self.label_voltage_range_c.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky='W')
        self.spin_voltage_range_c.grid(row=6, column=3)
        self.label_over_voltage_c.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky='W')
        self.label_heat_set_c.grid(row=8, column=2, sticky='W')
        self.spin_over_voltage_c.grid(row=7, column=3)
        self.entry_heat_set_c.grid(row=8, column=3)
        self.label_voltage_set_c.grid(row=6, column=4, sticky='W')
        self.label_meas_set_c.grid(row=7, column=4, sticky='W')
        self.label_set_time_c.grid(row=8, column=4, sticky='W')
        self.entry_voltage_set_c.grid(row=6, column=5)
        self.entry_meas_set_c.grid(row=7, column=5)
        self.entry_time_set_c.grid(row=8, column=5)
        self.label_set_delay_c.grid(row=6, column=6, sticky='W')
        self.label_set_repeat_c.grid(row=7, column=6, sticky='W')
        self.entry_delay_set_c.grid(row=6, column=7)
        self.entry_repeat_set_c.grid(row=7, column=7)
        self.check_instrument_c.grid(row=8, column=6, sticky='W')

        # Button
        self.frame_settings.grid(row=8)
        self.button_run.grid(row=8, column=0)
        self.button_stop.grid(row=8,column=1)
        self.button_quit.grid(row=8, column=2)


    # Function
    def about(self):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("About", "About" %chr(64))

    def on_quit(self):
        self.parent.quit()
        self.parent.destroy()
        self.fout.close()

    def save_file(self):
        self.file_opt = self.options = {}
        self.options['filetypes'] = [('Text Files', '.txt')]
        self.dataname = asksaveasfilename(**self.file_opt)
        self.datamode = 'a'

        try:
            self.fout = open(self.dataname, self.datamode)
        except Exception, e:
            strError = "Output file open error: "+ str(e)
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", strError)
    def on_stop(self):
        self.button_quit.configure(state='active')

    def on_run(self):
        self.button_quit.configure(state='disable')
        create_header = Header(gui.fout, self.selected_instruments_query(),self.dataname, self.voltage_range_a_var.get(),
                               self.voltage_set_a_var.get(), self.delay_set_a_var.get(), self.over_voltage_a_var.get(),
                               self.meas_set_a_var.get(), self.repeat_set_a_var.get(), self.heat_set_a_var.get(),
                               self.temp_sensor_a_var.get(), self.voltage_range_b_var.get(),
                               self.voltage_set_b_var.get(), self.delay_set_b_var.get(), self.over_voltage_b_var.get(),
                               self.meas_set_b_var.get(), self.repeat_set_b_var.get(), self.heat_set_b_var.get(),
                               self.temp_sensor_b_var.get(),self.voltage_range_c_var.get(),
                               self.voltage_set_c_var.get(), self.delay_set_c_var.get(), self.over_voltage_c_var.get(),
                               self.meas_set_c_var.get(), self.repeat_set_c_var.get(), self.heat_set_c_var.get(),
                               self.temp_sensor_c_var.get())

    def selected_instruments_query(self):
        selected_power_query = [self.instrument_var_a.get(), self.instrument_var_b.get(), self.instrument_var_c.get()]
        selected_multimeter_query = [self.temp_sensor_a_var.get(), self.temp_sensor_b_var.get(), self.temp_sensor_c_var.get()]
        selected_instruments_query = [selected_power_query,selected_multimeter_query]
        return selected_instruments_query


class Header:
    WRITE = 0
    def __init__(self,fout,selected_instruments,dataname,voltage_range_a_var,voltage_set_a_var, delay_set_a_var,
                 over_voltage_a_var,meas_set_a_var, repeat_set_a_var, heat_set_a_var, time_set_a_var, voltage_range_b_var,
                 voltage_set_b_var, delay_set_b_var,over_voltage_b_var,meas_set_b_var, repeat_set_b_var,
                 heat_set_b_var, time_set_b_var, voltage_range_c_var,voltage_set_c_var, delay_set_c_var,
                 over_voltage_c_var,meas_set_c_var, repeat_set_c_var, heat_set_c_var, time_set_c_var):

        self.fout = fout
        self.selected_instruments = selected_instruments
        self.dataname = dataname
        self.voltage_range_a_var = voltage_range_a_var
        self.voltage_set_a_var = voltage_set_a_var
        self.delay_set_a_var = delay_set_a_var
        self.over_voltage_a_var = over_voltage_a_var
        self.meas_set_a_var = meas_set_a_var
        self.repeat_set_a_var = repeat_set_a_var
        self.heat_set_a_var = heat_set_a_var
        self.time_set_a_var = time_set_a_var
        self.voltage_range_b_var = voltage_range_b_var
        self.voltage_set_b_var = voltage_set_b_var
        self.delay_set_b_var = delay_set_b_var
        self.over_voltage_b_var = over_voltage_b_var
        self.meas_set_b_var = meas_set_b_var
        self.repeat_set_b_var = repeat_set_b_var
        self.heat_set_b_var = heat_set_b_var
        self.time_set_b_var = time_set_b_var
        self.voltage_range_c_var = voltage_range_c_var
        self.voltage_set_c_var = voltage_set_c_var
        self.delay_set_c_var = delay_set_c_var
        self.over_voltage_c_var = over_voltage_c_var
        self.meas_set_c_var = meas_set_c_var
        self.repeat_set_c_var = repeat_set_c_var
        self.heat_set_c_var = heat_set_c_var
        self.time_set_c_var = time_set_c_var
        print self.selected_instruments
        # Header involve data only once
        if Header.WRITE == 0:
            self.header_file()
            Header.WRITE = 1

    def header_file(self):
        t = datetime.datetime.now()
        curr_datetime = t.timetuple()
        yr = str(curr_datetime[0])
        curr_date = "%02d."%int(yr[2:]) + "%02d."%curr_datetime[1] + "%02d."%curr_datetime[2]
        curr_time = "%02d:"%curr_datetime[3] + "%02d:"%curr_datetime[4] + "%02d"%curr_datetime[5]
        time_data = curr_date + " " + curr_time
        separate_line = "*"*120

        str_out_time = "Filename: \t%s \nTime/Date: \t%s \n\nInstrument - #A\n\n" % (self.dataname, time_data)
        self.fout.write(str_out_time)
        str_out_a = "Voltage Range: \t%d\tSet Voltage: \t%d\tMeasurement Delay: \t%d\n" \
                    "OVP: \t\t%d\tMeas.Set: \t%d\tRepeat: \t\t%d\n" \
                    "Heat.Set: \t%d\tTime Limit: \t%d\n\n\n" % (self.voltage_range_a_var,
                    self.voltage_set_a_var, self.delay_set_a_var, self.over_voltage_a_var,
                    self.meas_set_a_var, self.repeat_set_a_var, self.heat_set_a_var,
                    self.time_set_a_var)

        str_out_b = "Instrument - #B\n\nVoltage Range: \t%d\tSet Voltage: \t%d\tMeasurement Delay: \t%d\n" \
                    "OVP: \t\t%d\tMeas.Set: \t%d\tRepeat: \t\t%d\n" \
                    "Heat.Set: \t%d\tTime Limit: \t%d\n\n\n"  % (self.voltage_range_b_var,
                    self.voltage_set_b_var, self.delay_set_b_var, self.over_voltage_b_var,
                    self.meas_set_b_var, self.repeat_set_b_var, self.heat_set_b_var,
                    self.time_set_b_var)
        str_out_c = "Instrument - #C\n\nVoltage Range: \t%d\tSet Voltage: \t%d\tMeasurement Delay: \t%d\n" \
                    "OVP: \t\t%d\tMeas.Set: \t%d\tRepeat: \t\t%d\n" \
                    "Heat.Set: \t%d\tTime Limit: \t%d\n\n\n%s\n" % (self.voltage_range_c_var,
                    self.voltage_set_c_var, self.delay_set_c_var, self.over_voltage_c_var,
                    self.meas_set_c_var, self.repeat_set_c_var, self.heat_set_c_var,
                    self.time_set_c_var, separate_line)

        # Print header file depending of the instruments
        for condition, string in zip(self.selected_instruments[0], [str_out_a, str_out_b, str_out_c]):
            if condition:
                self.fout.write(string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    gui = Interface(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: too much code --  pls narrow to where your issue -- am assuming not all the code is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A terrifyingly simplified example of how you can use (and toggle) three different loops, running in parallel, (in this case) printing three different words.

Using Tkinters's `after()` method, these loops can run *inside* the main loop:

[image]

```
from Tkinter import *

class MultiLoop:

    def __init__(self):

        self.master = Tk()
        self.run1 = False
        self.run2 = False
        self.run3 = False

        button1 = Button(text="Toggle Monkey", command = self.togglemonkey).pack()
        button2 = Button(text="Toggle eats", command = self.toggleeats).pack()
        button3 = Button(text="Toggle banana", command = self.togglebanana).pack()
        # first call:
        self.master.after(0, self.loop1)
        self.master.after(0, self.loop2)
        self.master.after(0, self.loop3)

        self.master.mainloop()

    # The three loops
    def loop1(self):
        if self.run1 == True:
            print("Monkey")
        else:
            pass
        # schedule next run
        self.master.after(100, self.loop1)

    def loop2(self):
        if self.run2 == True:
            print("eats")
        else:
            pass
        # schedule next run
        self.master.after(1000, self.loop2)

    def loop3(self):
        if self.run3 == True:
            print("banana")
        else:
            pass
        # schedule next run
        self.master.after(2000, self.loop3)

    # The toggle functions
    def togglemonkey(self):
        self.run1 = True if self.run1 == False else False

    def toggleeats(self):
        self.run2 = True if self.run2 == False else False

    def togglebanana(self):
        self.run3 = True if self.run3 == False else False


MultiLoop()
```

Comment: ...but this is an example if you want only to execute one loop at the same time. For example, I need `loop2 ` and `loop3 `. execute at the same time.

Comment: @get_function did you try? you can run three loops at the same time. Just switch them on with the button: 1, 2 or all three together.

Comment: @ Jacob Vlijm: Thanks! My mistake, now I will try to solve my problem.

Comment: @get_function is this what yopu are looking for? If not, what *is* the question?

Comment: how can I do that with class ? For example: `def on_run(self):
               instrument_verification_power = instrument_verification[0]`also [Instrument A, b,C] - from which we can conclude what an Instrument should be included. `class LogicalUnit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.step = step
        start = 0
        while start != 100:
            measure voltage
            time.sleep(2)
            start += 1` - based on the Instrument verification decide how meny unit should be power on and create one, twoo or free class. Then worked the same measurement for all class.