# Python Tkinter While Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading, schedule

Well i am a bit of newb at python, and i am getting hard to make a thread in Tkinter , as you all know using while in Tkinter makes it Not Responding and the script still running.

```
  def scheduler():
    def wait():
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
        return
    Hours = ScheduleTest()
    if len(Hours) == 0:
        print("You need to write Hours, Example: 13:30,20:07")
    if len(Hours) > 0:
        print("Scheduled: ", str(Hours))
        if len(Hours) == 1:
            schedule.every().day.at(Hours[0]).do(Jumper)
            print("Will jump 1 time")
        elif len(Hours) == 2:
            schedule.every().day.at(Hours[0]).do(Jumper)
            schedule.every().day.at(Hours[1]).do(Jumper)
            print("Will jump 2 times")
        elif len(Hours) == 3:
            schedule.every().day.at(Hours[0]).do(Jumper)
            schedule.every().day.at(Hours[1]).do(Jumper)
            schedule.every().day.at(Hours[2]).do(Jumper)
            print("Will jump 3 times")
        while True:
            t = threading.Thread(target=wait)
            t.start()
    return
scheduler()
```

i have tried to do something like this but it still makes tkinter not responding
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply use after() http://stackoverflow.com/a/39632315/1391444 one, or more loops works equally.

Comment: Do you mean use after insread of sleep? like root.after(10000) instead of time,sleep? i have tried to do this but it didn't work , either i didn't understand where to put the after or it just didn't work for me

Comment: I have to run, but will be back if you don't manage.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I didn't manage, can you still help me ?

Comment: Sure, I will post an answer within a few hours.

Comment: Yes, Thank you , i am trying to understand it, it will take a while , but if i won't manage i will tell, thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, yes , i did manage , mainly i lisen to you by not use time.sleep, so i did after(2000, callfunction that contain schedule.run_pending())

Comment: You right its kinda fake while :) Thanks you are Awsome!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### When  to use the after method; faking while without threading

As mentioned in a comment, In far most cases, you do not need threading to run a "fake" while loop. You can use the `after()` method to schedule your actions, using `tkinter`'s `mainloop` as a "coat rack" to schedule things, pretty much exactly like you would in a while loop.

This works in all situations where you can simply throw out commands with e.g. `subprocess.Popen()`, update widgets, show messages etc.

It does *not* work when the scheduled process takes a lot of time, running *inside* the mainloop. Therefore `time.sleep()` is a bummer; it will simply hold the `mainloop`.

#### How it works

Within that limitation however, you can run complicated tasks, schedule actions even set `break` (-equivalent) conditions.

Simply create a function, initiate it with `window.after(0, <function>)`. Inside the function, (re-) schedule the function with `window.after(<time_in_milliseconds>, <function>)`.

To apply a break- like condition, simply rout the process (inside the function) not to be scheduled again.

#### An example

This is best illustrated with a simplified example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class TestWhile:
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.window = Tk()
        shape = Canvas(width=200, height=0).grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.showtext = Label(text="Wait and see...")
        self.showtext.grid(column=0, row=1)
        fakebutton = Button(
            text="Useless button"
            )
        fakebutton.grid(column=0, row=2)
        
        # initiate fake while
        self.window.after(0, self.fakewhile)
        self.cycles = 0
       
        self.window.minsize(width=200, height=50)
        self.window.title("Test 123(4)")
        self.window.mainloop()

    def fakewhile(self):
        # You can schedule anything in here
        if self.cycles == 5:
            self.showtext.configure(text="Five seconds passed")
        elif self.cycles == 10:
            self.showtext.configure(text="Ten seconds passed...")
        elif self.cycles == 15:
            self.showtext.configure(text="I quit...")
        """
        If the fake while loop should only run a limited number of times,
        add a counter
        """
        self.cycles = self.cycles+1
        """
        Since we do not use while, break will not work, but simply
        "routing" the loop to not being scheduled is equivalent to "break":
        """
        if self.cycles <= 15:
            self.window.after(1000, self.fakewhile)
        else:
            # start over again
            self.cycles = 0
            self.window.after(1000, self.fakewhile)
            # or: fakebreak, in that case, uncomment below and comment out the
            # two lines above
            # pass

TestWhile()
```

In the example above, we run a scheduled process for fifteen seconds. While the loop runs, several simple tasks are performed, in time, by the function `fakewhile()`.

After these fivteen seconds, we can start over again or "break". Just uncomment the indicated section to see...